# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for parameter binding must not be null or empty

Tags: java, sql, jpql

I'm currently getting this error regarding my jqpl query for ordering:

```
Name for parameter binding must not be null or empty! On JDKs < 8, you need to use @Param for named parameters, on JDK 8 or better, be sure to compile with -parameters
```

I'm on the former situation, so I need to use @Param but I'm unsure how to do this. This is the situation currently regarding my JPQL:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM DePerson p, DeClass c, DeSchool s" +
    "WHERE p.personId = c.id " +
    "AND su.schoolId = s.id " +
    "ORDER BY :ordering")
Page<DeSiteUser> orderingAll(Page page, String ordering, Pageable pageable);
```

So it's clear as day I need to implement @Param for the values I'm trying to pass in the ordering string. What I'm trying to achieve is implementing an ordering method that would allow a value such as:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/person?sorting=city
```

The value city to be passed into the query and then sort out the information based on that. That being the case, how would I pass in the @Param for my existing jpql to enable it to 1. work but 2. allow the ability for ordering. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@Param("ordering")`

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM DePerson p, DeClass c, DeSchool s" +
    "WHERE p.personId = c.id " +
    "AND su.schoolId = s.id " +
    "ORDER BY :ordering")
Page<DeSiteUser> orderingAll(@Param("ordering") String ordering, Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java version later than 8 you have to paste this into Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler:

```
-parameters
```

And in gradle.build:

```
compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs << '-parameters'
}
```